# How to close any dialog that run, without knowing which is the dialog?

Tags: android

I am looking for something like this...

```
Activity currentActivity = 
((MyApp)context.getApplicationContext()).getCurrentActivity();
```

...but for dialogs.

Something like `getCurrentView()` that returns the current view that runs in the front, and then I can close them from outside.

I don't have the instance of the dialog to call dismiss.

Is there any bind that I can control with him any window that run?

The dialogs I create are something like this:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setView(dialogView)
                .setTitle(mPolicyInterface.getTitle()).setMessage(mPInterface.getSubTitle());
```

Comment: you probably should store a singletone of that current dialog somewhere

Comment: are you using DialogFragment, a builder or something else?

Comment: I don't use DialogFragment ,I use Builder @NikosHidalgo

Comment: could you add some of the relevant code?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I added an example of a dialog I create

Comment: @batsheva you can create by statically in Helper or some kind of class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do it

1. to create a singleton object for that
2. To use a dialog fragment
3. set back press listener

   dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

   ```
                   @Override
                   public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                                        KeyEvent event) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                       //Back Key for edit shift amount fix
                       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                           return false;
                       }
                       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                           dialog.dismiss();
                       }
                       return true;
                   }
               });
   ```

Comment: thx for your answer, BTW it didn't help me, by me we have tons of dialogs, I can't replace them all with fragment dialog, or create a singleton for each of them,  and the back press you ordered is not getting clicked by my application, because I'm trying to force the application in some case to go to the main window, but if there was a dialog open there, this dialog does not close.